# How to get '2f8b547d..eb94967a' string from the log 'Updating 2f8b547d..eb94967a Fast-forward....' in shell?

Tags: shell

I am building a shell script.

The script gets git log such as:

```
"Updating 2f8b547d..eb94967a Fast-forward...."
```

but I want to get `2f8b547d..eb94967a` snippet.

I am a new one for the shell. So, Thanks for you help.

Update:

For the more, I want use the snippet as a param. Because I will excute 
`git log 2f8b547d..eb94967a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe it to `awk` like so:

```
echo "Updating 2f8b547d..eb94967a Fast-forward...." | awk '{print $2}'
```

Your result will be `2f8b547d..eb94967a`.

If it is a script, say, abc.sh that had such output, then you can run:

```
$> ./abc.sh | awk '{print $2}'
```

`awk` takes the output and splits the information by space. `Updating` is represented with $1. `2f8b547d..eb94967a` is $2 and so on. In the above example, we ask `awk` to print out the 2nd item in the output.

Comment: Thanks your answer, one more step. How do I get the output as a param? Because I will command `git log 2f8b547d..eb94967a` next.

Comment: For that, just do this: `$> ./abc.sh | awk '{print $2}' | xargs git log`

Comment: @ToddMark Do you mean *positional parameter* (e.g. argument to the script) or do you mean variable?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  positional parameter

Comment: Okay, then for both answers, you can use *command substitution*, e.g. `$(the command)` to make the result of `the command` available, e.g. `./yourscript.sh $(awk or cut command)`. If you were assigning to a variable, it would be `var=$(the command)`.

Comment: Thanks again. It's worked!. First time to learn the shell, this is a tough way.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `awk` (don't get me wrong, `awk` is super for this job as well), you can simply use `cut` with a `space` delimiter extract the second field, e.g.

```
cut -d' ' -f2 yourgit.log
```

You can also pipe output to `cut` or redirect the input file to it using `<` as well. It essentially does the same as the `awk` command, it just being a different choice of which utility to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here another alternative:

```
echo "Updating 2f8b547d..eb94967a Fast-forward...." | read u hash rest
```

After this, the string you are looking for is stored on the variable `hash`:

```
echo $hash
```